# Verilog implementation of serial receiver not behaving like simulation (in fact, it's doing nothing)

Tags: hardware, verilog, fpga, state-machine, uart

I have designed a simple implementation of a UART reciever using Verilog. I did it using the state machine approach.

Here is my code:

```
module my_serial_receiver(
    input clk,
    input reset_n,
    input Rx,
    output reg [7:0] received_byte,
    output reg byte_ready
);

parameter IDLE = 4'd0, BIT_0 = 4'd1, BIT_1 = 4'd2,
                BIT_2 = 4'd3, BIT_3 = 4'd4, BIT_4 = 4'd5, BIT_5 = 4'd6, 
                BIT_6 = 4'd7, BIT_7 = 4'd8, BYTE_READY = 4'd9;

reg [3:0] state = 0;
reg [8:0] baud_clock = 0;
reg baud_sync = 0;
reg baud_tick = 0;
reg baud_reset = 0;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (baud_reset) baud_clock <= 9'd1;
    else if (baud_sync) begin
        if (baud_clock == 9'd322) baud_clock <= 0;
        else baud_clock <= baud_clock + 9'd1;
    end
    else begin
        if (baud_clock == 9'd215) baud_clock <= 0;
        else baud_clock <= baud_clock + 9'd1;
    end
end

always @(*) begin
    baud_tick <= ~|baud_clock;
end

always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
    if (~reset_n) begin
        state <= IDLE;
        received_byte <= 8'h0;
    end
    else begin
    case(state)
        IDLE: begin
             byte_ready <= 0;
             if (Rx == 0) begin
                state <= BIT_0;
                baud_reset <= 1;
                baud_sync <= 1;
             end
        end
        BIT_0: begin
            baud_reset <= 0;
            if (baud_tick) begin
                baud_sync <= 0;
                received_byte[0] <= Rx;
                state <= BIT_1;
            end
        end
        BIT_1: begin
             if (baud_tick) begin
                received_byte[1] <= Rx;
                state <= BIT_2;
            end
        end
        BIT_2: begin
             if (baud_tick) begin
                received_byte[2] <= Rx;
                state <= BIT_3;
            end
        end
        BIT_3: begin
             if (baud_tick) begin
                received_byte[3] <= Rx;
                state <= BIT_4;
            end
        end
        BIT_4: begin
             if (baud_tick) begin
                received_byte[4] <= Rx;
                state <= BIT_5;
            end
        end
        BIT_5: begin
             if (baud_tick) begin
                received_byte[5] <= Rx;
                state <= BIT_6;
            end
        end
        BIT_6: begin
             if (baud_tick) begin
                received_byte[6] <= Rx;
                state <= BIT_7;
            end
        end
        BIT_7: begin
             if (baud_tick) begin
                received_byte[7] <= Rx;
                state <= BYTE_READY;
            end
        end
        BYTE_READY: begin
            if (baud_tick) begin
             byte_ready <= 1;
             state <= IDLE;
            end
        end
        default: state <= IDLE;
    endcase
    end
end 

endmodule
```

And here is a [picture of my simulation results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3EAG.jpg):

[image: waveform1]

For the simulation I sent the bytes 0x55, 0x11, 0x32, 0x63, and 0xFF. The byte_ready signal is asserted at the correct time for each of those bytes (for exactly one clock cycle). My simulation appears to be working perfectly.

I have even simulated for varying errors in baud rate. (Note: I am designing this to work with a baud rate of **115200**. The simulation still worked properly.

I have even used the Signaltap logic analyzer to confirm the incoming Rx signal. I even used Signaltap to observe the state progression of the system, but the state literally never changes. It stays right at the start even though I see Rx being received by the FPGA.

I have even changed it up to show different LEDs flashing for the states or bytes received. Nothing lights up.

It appears that the design is not reacting at all.

I am completely lost with regards of what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have managed to get the LEDs reacting. Now however it seems that the bytes I receive is completely random. Probing into the signals I realize the LSB of my state (state[0]) is progressing in a wrong manner, with comparison to the simulation.

It should be toggling for every single Rx bit received, but Signaltap reveals that it's doing something else.

[Signaltap and Modelsim waves](http://imgur.com/a/ZSK44) (The ModelSim one is what's supposed to be happening):

[image: signal-tap-waveform]
[image: model-sim-waveform]

How can I fix this discrepancy?

Comment: Have you verified the FPGA is working by, for example, blinking an LED?  What hardware and tool chains are you using?

Comment: Your code looks synthesizable to me (i.e. I don't see anything that would make it change between sim and fpga).  Have you loaded the design correctly and hooked up the inputs?  I think you need to tell us how you've done that and what FPGA you are using and the steps taken so we can tell why your design isn't loaded on the FPGA correctly.

Comment: It does seem that your design should progress out of the IDLE state once your Rx data is zero.  The only thing that will keep your state-machine in the IDLE state is if reset_n is zero. This may seem like a pretty obvious thing to check, but have you confirmed with signaltap that the reset_n signal is indeed high when Rx data is toggling?

Comment: Also, when setting up signaltap, make sure that you use the clock within your block to drive signaltap to ensure that the clock is actually making it into your block.  Same with the Rx and reset_n signals.  Make sure you don't grab them from a higher level of hierarchy in you design, make sure you select the signals that are actually in your block.

Comment: @Ciano Thank you so much for bringing up reset_n! I actually did forget it have it assigned to button, I did just that and now the LEDs do light up. I have edited my question with the new problem I'm facing.

Comment: As user11610 suggests, you do want to register the Rx signal, preferably twice, so to synchronize it to your clk signal.  It looks like on the hardware you're changing state very close to the edges where Rx changes.  You want to look at that and understand why.  In your simulation you change state about midway between Rx transition edges, which is what you want.  You want to be sure Rx is stable before you sample.

Answer (score 0):

It would be advisable to register the RX input before using in. The logic that uses it, can see it at different times (in relation to the clock) and some flops might toggle as if RX changed state, while other might not.

Also, it is not advisable to assign signals that are asynchronously reset in the same always block with the ones that aren't.

Comment: Hi, I tried buffering the signal using up to 5 buffers. It had no effect on the result. I still get completely unexpected results. For example, sending 0x55, I mostly get 0x30, all though sometimes it's something even different from that.